# When I right click drag my mouse to the right and left click browser tabs open (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, mouse

When I right click drag my mouse to the right and left click tabs open and this is a problem because I use my computer for games so when I aim to shoot and left click tabs open for my browser.

Is there a way to fix this problem? It's a major annoyance! I use Windows 10.

Comment: Some installed software must be doing it.

Comment: How would i find it?

Comment: [Boot into Safe mode](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10) to disable all third-party products and drivers. If the problem disappears, then the problem is some installed product. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Answer (score 0):

@harrymc I have reset my computer and even set it up with a new Microsoft account and I’m still having the problem

Comment: Change this to a comment. It should not be posted as an answer.